# unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component AboutComponent

Tags: typescript, angular, fullpage.js

Hello im trying to integrate ng2-fullpage into my anguar2 app. Whenever im trying to insert the directive [MnFullpageDirective] into the component its showing the aforementioned error

**Component with the problematic directive**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MnFullpageDirective } from 'ng2-fullpage';
import { AllPraniComponent } from './prani+room/allPrani.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'praniCool-about',
    template: `<div mnFullpage [mnFullpageNavigation]="true">
                  <div id="section1" class="section fp-section fp-table">
                      <praniCool-header></praniCool-header>
                  </div>
                  <div id="section2" class="section fp-section fp-table">
                      <praniAndroom></praniAndroom>
                  </div>
              </div>`,
    directives: [MnFullpageDirective, HeaderComponent, AllPraniComponent]
})

export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {}
```

**pranicool-header component**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'praniCool-header',
    templateUrl: 'app/header.component.html'
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit{}
```

**header.component.html**

```
<div class="header col-xs-12" >
  <div class="text-center vertical-center">
     <span id="p">p</span>
     <span id="r">r</span>
     <span id="a">a</span>
     <span id="n">n</span>
     <span id="i">i</span>
     <span id="c">C</span>
     <span id="o1">O</span>
     <span id="o2">O</span>
     <span id="l">L</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

**prani and room component**

same static content as header

**full Error Log**

EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'AboutComponent'

EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'AboutComponent'

STACKTRACE:
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'AboutComponent'
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:538)
    at zone.js:515
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:323)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.umd.js:6075)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:322)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:216)
    at zone.js:571
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:356)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.umd.js:6066)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:355)

Unhandled Promise rejection: Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'AboutComponent' ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: BaseException$1 {message: "Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'MainComponent'", stack: "Error: Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on t…st:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:216:44)"}message: "Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'AboutComponent'"stack: "Error: Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'AboutComponent'↵    at new BaseException$1 (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/compiler.umd.js:912:27)↵    at CompileMetadataResolver.getViewDirectivesMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/compiler.umd.js:10979:27)↵    at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/compiler.umd.js:13022:67)↵    at Array.forEach (native)↵    at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponent (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/compiler.umd.js:13019:40)↵    at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/compiler.umd.js:13009:53)↵    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:323:29)↵    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js:6075:45)↵    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:322:35)↵    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:216:44)"**proto**: Error
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'AboutComponent'(…)

**Systemjs.config.js**

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'ng2-fullpage':               'node_modules/ng2-fullpage'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  };
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  }
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

**updates**

I have 12 components like the following one.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

@Component({
  selector: 'biha',
  templateUrl: 'app/svg/Biha.svg'
})

export class BihaComponent implements OnInit {
     talkTalk:TimelineMax;

     constructor(private router: Router, private elementRef: ElementRef){
           setInterval(() => { this.clicked(); }, 1000*6 );
     }
     ngOnInit(){
            this.group = this.elementRef.nativeElement;

            this.earRight = this.group.querySelectorAll("#earRight");
            this.earLeft = this.group.querySelectorAll("#earLeft");

            this.talkTalk = new TimelineMax({
              paused: true
            });

            this.talkTalk
                .to(this.mouthOpen, 0, { visibility:"visible"})
                .to(this.mouthOpen, 0.2, { scaleY:0.9})
                .to(this.mouthOpen, 0.2, { scaleY:1})
                .to(this.mouthOpen, 0.5, { scaleY:0.9})
                .to(this.mouthOpen, 0.1, { scaleY:1})
                .to(this.mouthOpen, 0.1, { opacity:0})
                .to(this.smile, 0.3, { opacity:1});
   }
  }
```

**they get added up in the allPraniComponent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Router } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import { BihaComponent } from '../single-components/biha.component';
import other components (like BihaComponent);

@Component({
  selector:'praniAndroom',
  directives: [BihaComponent, ...(other components)],
  templateUrl: 'app/prani+room/allPrani.component.html'
})

export class AllPraniComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }
}
```

**allPraniComponent.html**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="boxInner>
            <biha class="prani"></biha>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="boxInner>
           other components get added up like this
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the directive code too please?

Comment: Can you please add the full error you get?

Comment: im afraid i dont have any directive code

Comment: Have you mapped `ng2-fullpage` in `system.config.js`. i think Angular2 doesnt know what `mnFullpage` is.

Comment: Looks fine. Hard to say now. But try to remove `AllpraniComponent` and run. Hard to diagnose.

Comment: Could it be that you have circular dependencies between components? (through `providers`)

Comment: the result is the same...unfortunately

Comment: Or do you have 2 components (or other classes) in one file?

Comment: that can be the chance, actually im working with lots of animated svg components..for simplicity i didnt provide full code. Im editing the question, please guide me if you have any other way